# Unable to view Raspberry Pi folders on my PC which did previously work

Tags: windows-7, raspberry-pi, wired-networking

I cannot view my Raspberry Pi folders on my Windows 7 PC which did previously work. The Pi used to show up as a device on my network. I had placed a shortcut on my desktop for quick access, but that no longer works either.  I can still access pi with SSH (Putty). I am new to the Pi and networking so I do not know where to start. Pi is running Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 18 2014, 05:13:23) [GCC 4.6.3] on linux2

Comment: While operating system are you using on the Raspberry Pi? If it's Raspbian or some other Debian-based system, `sudo service samba status` should show whether or not the samba server is running.  Samba is the service that handles Windows-based file and print sharing on Linux.  If it is not running, you can start it with `service samba start` (assuming you're on a Debian-based system).  Stating anything you may have recently changed may also help us zero in on the problem if it isn't just that the server isn't running.

Comment: I am running Raspian. I queried the status and both nmbd & smbd are running.

Comment: I seem to remember working on a WIFI sniffer I saw in an article which I could not get working. I will see if I can find a link.

Comment: I don't know if this will work, but here is the link: (http://issuu.com/themagpi/docs/issue24final/37?e=1)

Comment: Problem solved. I performed a 'sudo apt-get dist-upgrade' then a 'sudo apt-get update' and the Pi finally shows up on my network.  Thanks